# What Meta Resource Type's Can Be Used?

Tags: html, meta

I need to categorize my website so what meta resource types are you allowed to use???

```
<meta http-equiv="Resource-Type" content="document">
```

Oh and do you even use meta resource types to categorize?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use http-equiv meta to categorize. This is used to give information for the browser. The browser knows what kind of content is inside. But here is a list:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="date" />

<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="name=value; expires=Day, DD-MMM-YY HH:MM:SS ZON; path=url" />

<meta http-equiv=”content-encoding” content=”gzip” />

<meta http-equiv=”date” content=”date” />

<meta http-equiv=”last-modified” content=”date” />

<meta http-equiv=”location” content=”10; url” />

<meta http-equiv=”refresh” content=”10;url=url” />
```

This means that the page will refresh of refer to another location in 10 seconds

```
<meta http-equiv="window-target" content="location" />

<meta http-equiv="www-authenticate" content="" />

<meta http-equiv="pics-label" content="labellist" />

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="option" />

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />

<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />

<meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="language">

<meta http-equiv="page-enter" content="revealtrans(duration=seconds,transition=num)" />

<meta http-equiv="page-exit" content="revealtrans(duration=seconds,transition=num)" /> 

<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"/>
```

Comment: so there is no way to even categorize?

Comment: my website. Thats it.

Comment: Can you please show a link to your site. I don't understand what you want to categorize in your site. You want to categorize the content of you're site. Did you mean: [microformats](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard)

Comment: no i want to categorize my website as educational that way a computer can read that info and oh i don't know categorize it!

Comment: There is no need to do that. The only thing you have to do is to add the category in your keywords on your site. So you have to add the category in the title, keywords, description, h1-h6 and normal text. That's all. If you do this google knows your website is educational.

Comment: @el_coder I believe what you are looking for is resource-type meta tag. An example of one that would indicate the page is a document would be as follows: `<meta name="resource-type" content="document">` 

More information on the meta tag in general can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name